# Sliding tabs with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, android-pageradapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

I wanted to implement a Google Play Store-style menu with sliding tabs. I closely implemented this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html), however in my implementation I am launching asynchronous data loading through a CursorLoader, which I initialize in the instantiateItem method of the PagerAdapter inner class.

The problem is that the PagerAdapter calls instantiateItem twice (thus instantiating the views corresponding to two tabs), which launches the asynchronous process twice, and every time the user clicks on a different tab, it launches the asynchronous loading another two times, creating a giant unmanageable mess. How can I make the PagerAdapter call instantiateItem just once?

Thank you.

edit: Here is my code for my PagerAdapter sublcass, implementing the tutorial:

```
class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    /**
     * @return the number of pages to display
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the value returned from {@link #instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)} is the
     * same object as the {@link View} added to the {@link ViewPager}.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)
    /**
     * Return the title of the item at {@code position}. This is important as what this method
     * returns is what is displayed in the {@link SlidingTabLayout}.
     * <p>
     * Here we construct one using the position value, but for real application the title should
     * refer to the item's contents.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        CharSequence title = "default";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                title = "Happiness";
            break;

            case 1:
                title = "Intelligence";
            break;

            case 2:
                title = "Memory";
            break;

            case 3:
                title = "Personality";
            break;

            case 4:
                title = "Success & Failure";
            break;
        }

    return title;
    }
    // END_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)

    /**
     * Instantiate the {@link android.view.View} which should be displayed at {@code position}. Here we
     * inflate a layout from the apps resources and then change the text view to signify the position.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources
        ListView view = (ListView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.article_list,
                container, false);
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent1.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 1);
                getActivity().startService(intent1);

                getLoaderManager().initLoader(ARTICLE_LOADER, null, KnowledgeFragment.this);
                mArticleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
                view.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);

                Log.v("PagerAdapter", "Adapter Set");

                Log.v("PagerAdapter", "View added");

                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent2.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 2);
                getActivity().startService(intent2);

                getLoaderManager().initLoader(ARTICLE_LOADER, null, KnowledgeFragment.this);
                mArticleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
                view.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent3.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 3);
                getActivity().startService(intent3);

                getLoaderManager().initLoader(ARTICLE_LOADER, null, KnowledgeFragment.this);
                mArticleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
                view.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent4.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 4);
                getActivity().startService(intent4);

                getLoaderManager().initLoader(ARTICLE_LOADER, null, KnowledgeFragment.this);
                mArticleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
                view.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent intent5 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent5.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 5);
                getActivity().startService(intent5);

                getLoaderManager().initLoader(ARTICLE_LOADER, null, KnowledgeFragment.this);
                mArticleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
                view.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
                break;
        }

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the item from the {@link ViewPager}. In our case this is simply removing the
     * {@link View}.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]");
    }

}
```

I know it's the PagerAdapter's default behavior to call the method twice in order to optimise memory usage and for smooth scrolling. In essence I'm asking if there's a way to alter it.

Comment: add code, there should be changes in your code from the example you have taken.

Comment: add your custom adapter class code..

Comment: @HarshaVardhan again see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I use getItem instead of instantiateItem, see below:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MyFrag.newInstance(position);
}
```

Edit:

getItem() is in android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter and should be used with Fragments

Then your fragment can handle the loading on an individual basis.

Comment: In using this method, do I have to define a fragment for each "page" that corresponds to the current tab?

Comment: By the way I'm checking the PagerAdapter documentation and there's no getItem method in there. I'm not sure you understand my question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I am using android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter, and it requires a fragment for each item.